# How to convert SpatialPointDataFrame to normal dataframe in r?

Tags: r, spatial-data-frame

I could load shp file in r:

```
setwd("something")
shp = readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "shp_name")
```

Now, I want to convert that to a normal dataframe. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. It's just works like in general:

```
shp_df = as.data.frame(shp, xy = T)
```

You don’t always have to complicate things...